# Нет ли синтаксической ошибки в записи &(23[array]) в коде? Почему?

Tags: c++

```
int array[33];

if(&array[4] < &(23[array]))
{
    cout << "А";
} else {
    cout << "B";
}
```

Comment: Потому что записи `a[b]`и `b[a]` эквивалентны...

Comment: `A[B] === *(A + B) === *(B + A) === B[A]` => `array[23] === 23[array]`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Записи `a[b]` и `b[a]` эквивалентны, поскольку, в силу правил арифметики указателей,

```
a[b] == *(a + b) == *(b + a) == b[a]
```